# Rewrite URL on Site using Nginx

Tags: php, url, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewriting

I currently have my URL like so:

mysite.com/test/?country=uk&number=1234&search=British+Telecom&limit=8

which I want to be like this:

mysite.com/test/uk/1234/British-Telecom/8

I am familiar with Apache mod_rewrite to some extent but never come across Nginx version. Anyone have an idea?

Something else I found is that the site is Wordpress and normal pages work fine with the url being rewritten, but my code is in a separate non-wp folder. How come WP's .htaccess seems to work when Apache is not running?

Another complication is that I have Varnish cache working - could this interfere?

Answer (score 1):

you must capture get variables with `([^/]*)` regex and then use it with `$1`,`$2` ...

use a htaccess like this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$     ./yourScript.php?country=$1&number=$2&search=$3&limit=$4 [L]
```

> change `yourScript.php` with your script name .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I did state in my question that the rewrite is for Nginx not Apache. I did run your code through an Apache to Nginx converter and got this:
location /test {
  rewrite ^/test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?country=$1&number=$2&search=$3&limit=$4 break;
}
but it didn't work.

Comment: I also have Varnish running - could this interfere?

Comment: PS script it is running on is test/index.php

Comment: @CarlWilson , do like this : `RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$     
         test/index.php?country=$1&number=$2&search=$3&limit=$4 [L]`